# MongoDB, как сверить значения таблиц

Tags: mongodb

Имею три таблицы:

Одна таблица зависит от второй.

Третья - таблица отношений междуй первой и второй (по ObjectID).

Задача: в таблице отношений не должно быть "висячих" указателей.

Я, конечно, понимаю, что можно сделать циклом. Но хочется как-то более эффективно, с точки зрения производительности... Например, средствами монго.

Comment: а ты точно хотите использовать mongodb, ваша задача выглядит как many-to-many связь, и она легко и эффективно решается любой реляционной базой, или же если у вас связь не подразумевает большое кол-во документов, то можно обойтись и без неё, а создать один документ, с вложенным массивом, https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3

Comment: Там соотношения для файлов (для их контроля). Получается так, что этой коллекцией могут пользоваться несколько коллекций.